# Make a directive with minimal length "required"

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which adds % to every input.
I want to be able to make it "required". 
So that if only % exists it will be invalid.
 an additional requirement, is that the input field can be enabled/ disabled by the user (with ngDisabled). When it is disabled I don't need to make it "required".

I have tried to set ngMinLength=1, but then it doesnt show % as I want, when 
the input is empty, because it is invalid.
How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/jivangilad/uZvn3/

```
<input valid-num type="text"  ng-model="deal.cupon">

var portaldirectives = angular.module("portaldirectives", []);



portaldirectives.directive("validNum", function($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        priority: 1,
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(val) {

                if (val === undefined)
                    val = "";
                var formatedStr = val;
                if (val.indexOf("%") == -1)
                    formatedStr = val + "%";
                if (formatedStr !== val) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatedStr);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }

                var num = formatedStr.toString().replace(/\,/g, '').replace('%', '');
                return num;
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewvalue) {
                return viewvalue + "%";

            });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use design instead of logic for this problem. Like this:
[image]

Other way is to not add percent if viewvalue is falsey, so everything will work

```
ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(viewvalue) {
    return viewvalue? viewvalue + "%" : '';
});
```

Comment: It seems that you put an image which I cannot see.